# Retrieve unique list of classes that implement multiple of the same generic interface

Tags: c#, reflection

Hope the title wasn't too confusing but here goes.

Say I have a generic interface

```
public interface IBase<T>{
}
```

Followed by classes that implement multiple of the interfaces (but with different generic) like so:

```
public class Base : IBase<TypeA>, IBase<TypeB>{
}
```

How would I retrieve list of classes that implemented the interface?
My current solution :

```
from x in AppDomain.currentDomain.GetAssemblies()
   .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
   from z in x.GetInterfaces()
   where
   z.IsGenericType &&
   basetype.IsassignableFrom(z.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
   select x
```

Issue with this is that it retrieves multiple of the same classes.

Any assistance will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with Distinct<>().

```
(from x in AppDomain.currentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    from z in x.GetInterfaces()
    where
    z.IsGenericType &&
    basetype.IsassignableFrom(z.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
    select x)
    .Distinct();
```

Comment: ugh so simple! Thank you!